# JAVASCRIPT i can't use cloneNode?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want to clone this:

```
<div class="media" id='this_comment'>
<a class="media-left" href="#">link</a>
<p>something</p>
</div>
```

with:

```
var x = $('#this_comment');
var clone = x.content.cloneNode(true);
```

I tried clone = x.cloneNode(true), clone = x.clone(true) but the console still throws
"Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined at ..."
Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

As `cloneNode()` is a vanilla JS method, you can not use that on a JQuery referenced element.

Though `x.clone(true)` should work. Probably, your script is running before the DOM is fully loaded. You can either place the script at the bottom of the *body* or wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function(){`.

**Demo:**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('#this_comment');
    var clone = x.clone(true).appendTo( "body" );
  });
</script>

<div class="media" id='this_comment'>
  <a class="media-left" href="#">link</a>
  <p>something</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
var clone = x.cloneNode(true);
```

Also, you need to use the cloned item insertion method. Like this:

```
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#this_comment');
var clone = x.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

```html
<div class="media" id='this_comment'>
  <a class="media-left" href="#">link</a>
  <p>something</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Though Mamun's answer is correct given the jQuery, the appendChild method is necessary for using the vanilla cloneNode method.